# Access AudioPlayer object from other class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudioplayer

How can one stop all running audio objects from one class when the audioplayer object are created in other classes?

This is for a menu consisting of multiple view controllers.

I create and play the sound using the audioplayer object in the first menu screen, and want to stop the sound in one or two of the other viewcontrollers.

How is this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to create a class that manages the audioplayer. Other classes then can request it to play/stops sounds.  Create one instance of this class and provide reference to it to all the view controllers.  Then when a view controller needs to stop/start sounds it will request it.

Comment: This sounds great but I am not sure how to do it.How are the audio objects declared and called? [AudioManager.someAudioPlayer play]; ?